# What do you call an airplane that is going down and about to crash?

Tags: phrase-requests

Example sentence:

> The plane went on a __ for a few minutes before crashing into the Pacific
>   Ocean.

I thought the word was *down dive* or something like that. But a Google search told me that I was wrong.

What's the correct term to use here?

Comment: What the plane did would depend on the circumstances. It might glide, it might spiral down, it might plunge/dive or it might disintegrate/come apart.

Comment: @RonaldSole So, "the plane went into a *dive* before crashing"?

Comment: *A dive* implies that the aircraft is heading (almost) vertically down. But an aircraft that runs out of fuel might well glide for a great distance before crashing. *Tailspin * and *spiral* are ways of describing an aircraft's behaviour as it descends - although it may recover rather than crashing.

Comment: If it took ten minutes it was probably not a dive or tailspin, unless the initial altitude was quite high.

Comment: @HotLicks - it can be both..it just depends on the altitude.

Comment: _Descend_ might be a suitable word

Comment: If this is about MH370 the plane never crashed.  In fact, it never even took off, but was spirited into a hanger by aliens after boarding.  The "debris" that has been found is all a smoke screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Tailspin](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tailspin):***

> - [ C usually singular ] a situation in which a plane turns round and round as it falls quickly towards the ground.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***[Go into a tailspin](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+into+a+tailspin):***

> Lit. ***[for an airplane] to lose control and spin to the earth, nose first.***
>
> - *The plane shook and then suddenly went into a tailspin. The pilot was not able to bring the plane out of the tailspin, and it crashed into the sea.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs

[image] From Life of Bon

Or ***[nosedive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nosedive)***: (verb)

> (of an aircraft) make a nosedive.
>
> - ‘the plane nosedived into the ground and exploded’

(noun)

> A steep downward plunge by an aircraft.
>
> - ‘the pilot put the plane in a nosedive and ejecte

(ODO)

[image] From Pinterest

Comment: If it took ten minutes to crash it was almost certainly not a nosedive, and likely not a tailspin.

Comment: @HotLicks - the time  depends on the altitude the plane was flying.

Comment: @Josh a nosedive is too fast to take 10 minutes from any aircraft altitude. It would be faster than cruising speed, which is not far short of 600 mph, so in a sixth of an hour it would fall 100 miles. Above 62 miles is regarded as outside the atmosphere.

Comment: Pan Am 103 that crashed over Lockerbie in Scotland on 21/12/1988, after a bomb exploded in the hold, is reported to have taken 36" to hit the ground. https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2000/feb/27/lockerbie.life1